# grep : Traversal results in a loop

Tags: unix, grep, aix

I did a recursive grep in current directory by following command.

```
grep -r -s <searchterm> .
```

But it says on output lines but all but on some output lines as below.

```
 Traversal results in a loop.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-r` flag follows symbolic links which may result in an infinite loop in cases when an inner directory is a symbolic link to an outer one. You can use the `-R` flag to not follow symbolic links. On the other hand, the error harmless. If you want to follow symbolic links use `-r` and let grep warn you when a possible cycle is detected.